# Can't use WpfAnimatedGif nuget package

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, nuget-package, animated-gif

I'm trying to make a WPF project that use nuget package of "WpfAnimatedGif" (https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif) in order to make a window background gif.
But for some reason, i can't use this package after i install it. I try to use namespaces of the package, for example:

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Resources\animated.gif"
       gif:ImageBehavior.AutoStart="True"
       gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="1"/>
```

but the visual studio show erros like:
"The namespace prefix "gif" is not defined."
What can i do to solve this problem?
thank you.

This is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TriviaGame.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TriviaGame"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Resources\animated.gif"
       gif:ImageBehavior.AutoStart="True"
       gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix it's complaining about is an xmlns. You're missing:

```
 xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
```

See the example code on github.

https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif